# Update all COLUMN_ID incrementally

Tags: android

After I delete a row in my SQLLite table, I need to update all the values of COLUMN_ID "_id" to new values incrementally - renumbering -

I could update them in sequence one by one, but is there away to update them at one, but in incremental order?

Comment: You should not rely on this to identify rows.  Instead, use your own ID column.  The _id column is intended to guarantee unique primary keys and for referential integrity.  The latter would give you a big problem if you update the values.

Comment: I don't think you need to update any values. Why don't you just order by the column_id, and get the top however many rows and assign them an incremental number on runtime? then again, I don't know much about your project...

Comment: the issue is: I use COLUMN_ID "_id" in "View getView()" in "ArrayAdapter" to find row, however, if one row is deleted, it create a problem as as "View getView()" return null.